# partly closed worker in workgroup

Tags: opencl

lets consider, when having multiple workgroups with multiple workers inside in OpenCL.
In case we have as mush workers in a workgroup as "cores" on the GPU, the GPU will sequential work the workgroups where each worker in a workgroup in parallel (right?). After finishing one workgroup, the next workgroup will be executed.
In case we have mush less worker in a workgroup than "cores" on the GPU, as far as I understood the GPU would execute multiple workgroups in parallel where of cause multiple workers are executed in parallel (right?). In this case, what would happen when this code will be executed?

```
__kernel void vector_add(__global const int *A) 
{ 
    // Get the index of the current element to be processed
    int i = get_global_id(0);
    if(A[i] == 0)
    {
        return; //stop like the half of all workers in a workgroup
    }
    // Do some time consuming calculation
    ...
}
```

This code will lead to "branching", but some worker in a workgroup will directly stop (return) where others do some time consuming calculation. Can we call this "branching"?
The big question: What will the "cores" which have returned do? Are they waiting till every worker in the workgroup finishes his job? Or because lot of them are returning at the same time, do they jump to the next workgroup to execute?

Is the behavior vendor specific? Or is this case properly defined in OpenCL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have branching in a kernel and within a work group some workers do branch A and some branch B, all workers have to compute both branches and discard the non-used branch result respectively. This negatively impacts execution time and is the reason why branching on GPUs should be avoided if possible. In your example with the empty `return` branch, if only one worker in the workgroup has to do the `time consuming calculation`, all the other workers have to wait, blocking hardware resources for other workgroups. If workgroups are small and you are lucky that all threads do the `return` branch, then that particular workgroup is executed very fast.

The matching between physical GPU "cores" and work group size is irrelevant for the computation results, but can impact performance to some extent. Workgrouop size should be a multiple of 32 (the GPU subdivides its "cores" into groups of 32, so-called warps). So if workgroup size is 16, half of the GPU will always be idle. If the workgroup size is extraordinarily large on the other hand (like 1024) and you have branching in the kernel, then it is less likely that all workers do the same branch and you end up in the above scenario.

Workgroup size is a bit of a tradeoff sometimes, if you need communication across the workgroup via `local` memory. Larger workgroup allows for more local communication, but increases "double-branch" likelyhood. If you don't use `local` memory, you can freely tune workgroup size for best performance (usually 64-256).

Ideally you want to saturate the GPU with millions of threads to have no idle "cores" and best performance.

Comment: Thanks for the well explained response! When I understand correctly, it also means: that different workgroups can work on different branches at the same time... for example workgroup 1 is working on branch A at the same time when workgroup 2 is working on branch B. Is that correct? That would also mean, that sorting the condition before executing the kernel seems to be a good idea.

Comment: Yes exactly. As long as all workers within a workgroup execute the same branch, performance is good. Different work groups can execute different branches concurrently.